# Mousemove with wrong position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created this little gallery with simple scaling effect based on position of mouse related to the center of image [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/4qkk1Lpn/)
it works very well but only if the contaienr has 100% width , if i change the width to 50% and margin in to the center it complety ruins the script as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gj221c1r/) What causes this unwanted behaviot of position of mouse?
I am calculating the distance with basic vectors operation e.g

```
 function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offsetLeft + (elem.offsetWidth / 2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offsetTop + (elem.offsetHeight / 2)), 2)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second version doesnt take the margin into consideration. In the first example the margin is 0 and thus not needed, try this:

```
function calculateDistance(elem, mouseX, mouseY) {
    return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseX - (elem.offsetLeft + nav.offsetLeft + (elem.offsetWidth / 2)), 2) + Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offsetTop + (elem.offsetHeight / 2)), 2)));
}
```

Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/caeth/gj221c1r/2/